# What does it mean when progression is resolved?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

I saw this text inside a very basic piano workbook in which I'm not sure what the author means by using "resolve".

> Progression #1: C-F-G-F-C
>
> NOTE: This 4 bar progression resolves back to C after the final time it's played on the play  along CD.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resolve?fromAsk=true&o=100500) gives this definition for "resolve" as used in music:

> Resolve: [Music] to progress from a dissonance to a consonance.

But the problem is that I don't here any dissonance on the above progression. C, F, and G totally sound harmonic and simply good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try playing a sequence C - F - G - F in a loop. Think of it as the basis of a song. This is probably what you'll hear on your play-along CD.

Now see what happens if you simply stop after the final F.

Most people would agree that it hasn't ended properly. It's hanging; the listener expects something else. It is *unresolved*.

Now try ending by adding that final C after the last F. Now it sounds as if it's finished.

Because the sequence starts with a C chord, and because all of the chords use notes from the C major scale, C feels like the "home" chord.

When you move away from the home chord, you introduce a tension - not a dissonance -- and when you return to the home chord, you *resolve* that tension.

Some pieces defy expectations by ending on an unresolved chord. But if your aim is to make the listener comfortable; to have that sense of closure; then resolving to the home chord is the conventional thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Slim. 2 more questions. First, so you believe this definition is not a good one and it shouldn't be called dissonance?! Second, Is resolving only called to this kind of ending?

Comment: The dictionary definition is correct but too specific. Resolving could be informally described as going from anything "nasty" to something "nice" - discord to harmony; unsynchronized rhythms to synchronized; uncomfortable chord to comfortable chord.

Answer (score 5):

"Resolution" has a slightly broader definition than just "from dissonance to consonance." Before I get to that, though, I want to touch on why exactly that definition is used.

First, let's throw out the chord progression you supplied: it's very 60's doo-wop, and not a good example for common practice harmony. Let's replace it with `|: C F C G :| C` (I am using `|: - :|` to indicate repeats.)

We are playing in the key of C major. This is clear from the fact that we start and end on that chord, and all of the other chords contain notes within the key of C major. This means that our C chord is called the **tonic** chord. It functions as a "home base," if you will. In common practice harmony, a **dominant** chord is one that implies a following resolution to a **tonic** chord. There are many other names for different chord functions in a key, including **mediant**, **sub-mediant**, **sub-dominant**. I am only going to focus on dominant and tonic here, so you should know that we use `I` (Roman numeral one) to refer to the **tonic** chord built on the root note of the key (C), and `V` (Roman numeral five) to refer to the **dominant** chord built on the 5th note of the key (G).

Back to our progression. Let's change it once more, to `|: C F C G7 :| C`. With Roman numerals, we would use `|: I IV I V7 :| I`. This is where we get the dissonance that your original definition was talking about. The `V7` chord is called a **dominant 7th**, because it contains a **tritone** that *strongly* implies a **resolution** to the tonic chord. (The dissonant tritone is caused by the 7th chord member, in this case, F.)

To exemplify this, play G7 as follows: G - F - B (from the bottom of the chord to the top). The F with the B above forms a dissonant interval of a **tritone**. It should sound odd and unstable. To resolve this chord to our consonant **tonic** chord of C, move the B up half a step, move the F down half a step, and move the G down a 5th to C. We are **resolving** the dissonant **tritone** outward by half-step to our consonant **tonic** chord.

So, that's essentially where your resolution definition is coming from. Now, let's bring it back to your original example step-by-step.

If we consider `G - C` in C major (`V - I`), we don't have a dominant 7th chord to fuel our resolution, but it really isn't necessary. If the entire piece has been in C major this whole time, the listener is going to expect the piece to end on the tonic I chord. We call this ending a [**cadence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_%28music%29), essentially meaning a kind of chord-to-chord resolution. The `V` chord (G) still has dominant function in the key of C major, so we can say we are resolving to C, EVEN THOUGH the G chord IN ISOLATION sounds like it doesn't need to go anywhere. Context is incredibly important in music theory and analysis.

Now, back to our original example of `|: C F G F :| C`, or `|: I IV V IV :| I`. The **cadence** we are analyzing is `IV - I`, or F - C. We are *still* in the key of C major, so the ear is going to expect the piece to end on the `I` chord, C. We can call it a resolution from F to C *because* the ear expects this in context. The `IV - I` chord progression actually has a special name: the "[Plagal cadence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_%28music%29#Plagal_cadence)". It is easily remembered since it is commonly used to set the text "A-men" at the end of hymns.

As slim alluded to, a better definition for "resolution" might be a "release of musical tension". Dissonance causes musical tension, as does moving away from the **tonic** "home" chords. The tension is then released by **resolving** back to the tonic.

Comment: Comprehensive musical answer!